# Vimeo video not fitting properly on UIWebView, swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiwebview, vimeo

I finally managed to show my vimeo video in a UIWebView. The size of the UIWebView is w=280, h = 204.

This is how the video is fitted in the UIWebView:

[image]

And then i can drag the video to its place where i would like it to be in the first place when the view is loaded:

[image]

This is the code i am using to show the video:

```
let embedHTML="<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body {background-color: transparent;color: white;}</style></head><body style=\"margin:0\"><iframe src=\"//player.vimeo.com/video/171151492?autoplay=1&amp;loop=1\" width=\"280\" height=\"204\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>";

webView.delegate = self
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://player.vimeo.com/video/171151492")!
webView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML as String, baseURL:url )
```

Comment: https://github.com/satishVekariya/LXVimeoKit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view controller tries to adjust the scroll view insets of `UIWebView` to your navigation bar.

You can set your view controller's `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property to false as below to prevent this:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Or from Interface Builder, untick the “Adjust Scroll View Inset” option of the view controller under Layout section.